# Angular Slider using $http and ui.router data not changing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-services

I am creating a basic slider using HTTP service from a local JSON file. Everything works if I don't use `ui.router`, when implementing `ui.router`, routing is working but the slider(next, previous button) is not changing the data .I have my `route.js` and `controller.js` below is my code. i consoled object and is logging. but not throwing any error scope.showprice,showavail etc and see the data changing in the log. but not in the ui view.

```js
app.controller('myctrl',function ($scope,$http) {

    $scope.productpage =" Product Page";
    $scope.gcpro =" Gc-pro Page";
    $scope.lessons =" Lessons Page";
    $scope.outlet =" Outlet Page";
    $scope.platinum ="The platinum Page";
    $scope.rental =" Rental Page";
    $scope.repairs =" Repairs Page";
    $scope.usedgear ="Usedgear Page";
    $scope.vintage =" Vintage Page";

    var jdata=0;
    var ctrl =this;
    $scope.reveal= function (){

        $scope.showsub=true;


    }

    $scope.notreveal= function(){

        $scope.showsub=false;
    }

    $http.get("../json/myJson.json")
        .then(function(response) {
            ctrl.sdata = response.data;
            console.log(ctrl.sdata);

            $scope.showprice = ctrl.sdata.allProducts[0].price;
            $scope.showavail = ctrl.sdata.allProducts[0].stockavailability;
            $scope.showdescribe= ctrl.sdata.allProducts[0].discription;
            $scope.showreview = ctrl.sdata.allProducts[0].custmerreviews;
            $scope.showimage = ctrl.sdata.allProducts[0].image;






        });

   $scope.slider= function (i) {


        $http.get("../json/myJson.json")
            .then(function(response) {
                ctrl.sdata = response.data;

                jdata = jdata+i;

                if (jdata < 0) {

                    jdata = ctrl.sdata.allProducts.length - 1;
                }

                if (jdata > ctrl.sdata.allProducts.length - 1) {

                    jdata = 0;
                }

                $scope.showprice = ctrl.sdata.allProducts[jdata].price;
                $scope.showavail = ctrl.sdata.allProducts[jdata].stockavailability;
                $scope.showdescribe = ctrl.sdata.allProducts[jdata].discription;
                $scope.showreview = ctrl.sdata.allProducts[jdata].custmerreviews;
                $scope.showimage = ctrl.sdata.allProducts[jdata].image;
console.log($scope.showprice);
            })
    }

});
```

```js
app.config(function ($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider,    $locationProvider
) {



    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home')


    $stateProvider.state('home',
        {

            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: '../html/home.html',
            controller: 'myctrl'


        })

        .state('products',

            {

                url: '/products',
                templateUrl: '../html/products.html',
                controller: 'myctrl'


            })
        .state('gcpro',

            {

                url: '/gcpro',
                templateUrl: '../html/gcpro.html',
                controller: 'myctrl'


            })
        .state('lessons',

            {

                url: '/lessons',
                templateUrl: '../html/lessons.html',
                controller: 'myctrl'


            })
        .state('outlet',

            {

                url: '/outlet',
                templateUrl: '../html/outlet.html',
                controller: 'myctrl'


            })
        .state('platinum',

            {

                url: '/platinum',
                templateUrl: '../html/platinum.html',
                controller: 'myctrl'


            })
        .state('rental',

            {

                url: '/rental',
                templateUrl: '../html/rental.html',
                controller: 'myctrl'


            })
        .state('repairs',

            {

                url: '/repairs',
                templateUrl: '../html/repairs.html',
                controller: 'myctrl'


            })
        .state('usedgear',

            {

                url: '/usedgear',
                templateUrl: '../html/usedgear.html',
                controller: 'myctrl'


            })
        .state('vintage',

            {

                url: '/vintage',
                templateUrl: '../html/vintage.html',
                controller: 'myctrl'


            })

})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <title></title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/css.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//unpkg.com/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body  >
<div id="wraper"  >
    <div id="header">

        <img src="../images/guitar1.png" id="topscreenshot" >
        <input type="text" id="topinput" placeholder="Enter keywords, Item # or Catalog #">

    </div>

    <div id="mainpage" ng-controller="myctrl as ctrl">

    <div id="navbardiv">

<span id="allnavbars" ng-mouseenter="reveal()" ng-mouseleave="notreveal()">

    <a ui-sref ="home"><button class="navbarbuttons">Home</button></a>
     <a ui-sref ="products"><button class="navbarbuttons">Product</button></a>
        <a ui-sref ="usedgear"><button class="navbarbuttons">Used Gear</button></a>
          <a ui-sref ="platinum"><button class="navbarbuttons">Platinum</button></a>
             <a ui-sref ="vintage"><button class="navbarbuttons">Vintage</button></a>
                <a ui-sref ="outlet"> <button class="navbarbuttons">Outlet</button></a>
                    <a ui-sref ="gcpro"> <button class="navbarbuttons">GC Pro</button></a>
                        <a ui-sref ="lessons"><button class="navbarbuttons">Lessons</button></a>
                            <a ui-sref ="repairs"><button class="navbarbuttons">Repairs</button></a>
                                <a ui-sref ="rental"><button class="navbarbuttons">Rentals</button></a>

      </span>

    </div>

    <div id="undernavbargrey">
      <span id="dropdownspan" ng-show="showsub" >

       <a href="#" class="anchorsss">Guitars</a>
       <a href="#" class="anchorsss">Bass</a>
       <a href="#" class="anchorsss">Amps Effects</a>
       <a href="#" class="anchorsss">Drums</a>
       <a href="#" class="anchorsss">Recording</a>
       <a href="#" class="anchorsss">Software</a>
       <a href="#" class="anchorsss">keyboards MIDI</a>
       <a href="#" class="anchorsss">Mics Wireless</a>
       <a href="#" class="anchorsss">Live Sound</a>
       <a href="#" class="anchorsss">DJ</a>
       <a href="#" class="anchorsss">Lighting</a>
       <a href="#" class="anchorsss">Accessories</a>
       <a href="#" class="anchorsss">Band Orchestra</a>
       </span>

    </div>

    <div id="greyline"></div>

    <div id="leftpadamdiv"> <img src="../images/left.png" id="leftpadam" ng-click="slider(-1)" ></div>

    <div id="rightpadamdiv"><img src="../images/right.png" id="rightpadam" ng-click="slider(1)" ></div>

    </div>


<div ui-view>



</div>



    <div id="therestdiv">
        <img src="../images/therest.png" id="therestpic">
    </div>







</div>


<script src = "../script/module.js"></script>
<script src="../script/controller.js"></script>
<script src="../script/route.js"></script>


<script src="../script/cdirective.js"></script>




</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: what's the version of `ui-router` you are using?

Comment: hey i accidentally had the old version of ui router. so the transition problem was fixed

Comment: But the data still not changing. i updated the question please read if you can

Comment: is `$http.get("../json/myJson.json")` this file is getting called? check network tab once.

Comment: yes that's the file . I console log all the response and the data is changing in console. So the api call is working . When i removed ui. router, ui view and use simple html binding, then it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First issue you posted is the issue with your `ui-router` version. Please update the `ui-router` version as your current version doesn't handle `transition` issue.

[Here is the reference for that issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/3246)

For the second issue, check if that Json file is getting called,

use `$resource` to fetch the data from a json file.

```
$scope.slider= function (i) {
    $resource('app/data.json', {}, {
        query: {
        method: 'GET',
        }
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        ctrl.sdata = response.data;

        jdata = jdata+i;

        if (jdata < 0) {

            jdata = ctrl.sdata.allProducts.length - 1;
        }

        if (jdata > ctrl.sdata.allProducts.length - 1) {

            jdata = 0;
        }

        $scope.showprice = ctrl.sdata.allProducts[jdata].price;
        $scope.showavail = ctrl.sdata.allProducts[jdata].stockavailability;
        $scope.showdescribe = ctrl.sdata.allProducts[jdata].discription;
        $scope.showreview = ctrl.sdata.allProducts[jdata].custmerreviews;
        $scope.showimage = ctrl.sdata.allProducts[jdata].image;
        console.log($scope.showprice);
    })
}
```

**`Dont forget to add`ngResource`in the module.`**

**Edit:** I prefer to add the `api` calls and the `data json` calls in a separate service.

Here is an example of such service:

```
(function(myApp) {
    'use strict';

        myApp.factory('DataService',DataService);

        function DataService($resource)
            {
            return $resource('app/data.json', {}, {
                query: {
                method: 'GET',
            }
        });
    }
})(myApp);
```

**Home.html**:

```
    <div id="greyline"></div>

        <div id="leftpadamdiv"> <img src="../images/left.png" id="leftpadam" ng-click="slider(-1)" ></div>

        <div id="rightpadamdiv"><img src="../images/right.png" id="rightpadam" ng-click="slider(1)" ></div>

        </div>
.........
........
// your remaining code
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/css.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//unpkg.com/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wraper"  >
    <div id="header">
        <img src="../images/guitar1.png" id="topscreenshot" >
        <input type="text" id="topinput" placeholder="Enter keywords, Item # or Catalog #">
    </div>
    <div id="mainpage">
    <div id="navbardiv">
<span id="allnavbars" ng-mouseenter="reveal()" ng-mouseleave="notreveal()">
    <a ui-sref ="home"><button class="navbarbuttons">Home</button></a>
     <a ui-sref ="products"><button class="navbarbuttons">Product</button></a>
        <a ui-sref ="usedgear"><button class="navbarbuttons">Used Gear</button></a>
          <a ui-sref ="platinum"><button class="navbarbuttons">Platinum</button></a>
             <a ui-sref ="vintage"><button class="navbarbuttons">Vintage</button></a>
                <a ui-sref ="outlet"> <button class="navbarbuttons">Outlet</button></a>
                    <a ui-sref ="gcpro"> <button class="navbarbuttons">GC Pro</button></a>
                        <a ui-sref ="lessons"><button class="navbarbuttons">Lessons</button></a>
                            <a ui-sref ="repairs"><button class="navbarbuttons">Repairs</button></a>
                                <a ui-sref ="rental"><button class="navbarbuttons">Rentals</button></a>

      </span>

    </div>

    <div id="undernavbargrey">
      <span id="dropdownspan" ng-show="showsub" >

       <a href="#" class="anchorsss">Guitars</a>
       <a href="#" class="anchorsss">Bass</a>
       <a href="#" class="anchorsss">Amps Effects</a>
       <a href="#" class="anchorsss">Drums</a>
       <a href="#" class="anchorsss">Recording</a>
       <a href="#" class="anchorsss">Software</a>
       <a href="#" class="anchorsss">keyboards MIDI</a>
       <a href="#" class="anchorsss">Mics Wireless</a>
       <a href="#" class="anchorsss">Live Sound</a>
       <a href="#" class="anchorsss">DJ</a>
       <a href="#" class="anchorsss">Lighting</a>
       <a href="#" class="anchorsss">Accessories</a>
       <a href="#" class="anchorsss">Band Orchestra</a>
       </span>
    </div>

<div ui-view>
</div>

<div id="therestdiv">
    <img src="../images/therest.png" id="therestpic">
</div>
</div>
<script src = "../script/module.js"></script>
<script src="../script/controller.js"></script>
<script src="../script/route.js"></script>
<script src="../script/cdirective.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Check I removed controller in index.html**

Comment: can you paste the view?

Comment: i added a screen shot of my log also put html . please check

Comment: what are the lines you console' d? and where did you  use `ctrl.sdata`, I mean in which controller?

Comment: i used ctrl.sdata  in ui view. so controller is defined in the state and using a home.html to show. the array 0 is showing like the picture. (i have update the question with more picture ,i am not sure  if you saw)The price,guitar picture, description etc are showing . its just not showing array 1,2,3,4.. when clicking  next button ,eventhough when console logging , the array is changing( see the log in the picture)

Comment: so when i did "console.log($scope.showprice)" each price is chaning in the log from array 0-7 when clicking next button, but not updating in the view. The view expressed in home.html is working . i tested it by pasting directly without using ui router. but when using ui router the view is not updating even thou its loging

Comment: the reason why the view is not updating is because the view is inside the `home state` and the `slider function` is outside it. what you can do is move the `div` that contains the sliders into `home.html`  and place it above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133317/discussion-between-sravan-and-anu-rajan).

Comment: That's it .omg, thank- you so much. moving the ng-click function button to home.html fixed it. So the function cant be out side the state.

Comment: yes, because you are using the `scope` for `home.html` page, you should have the view related to it in the respective page.